# Descargar un archivo CSV de un PLC de Siemens y borrarlo a continuación

Tags: php, descarga

He estado tratando de acceder a un PLC de Siemens para descargar un archivo CSV (que puede cambiar de nombre cada vez que se crea). Yo con mi PC puedo entrar y manipular sin problema, pero quiero que el programa lo haga automáticamente o completando un pequeño formulario. Para ello he escrito un código en PHP que en mi ordenador funciona, pero que cuando lo pruebo dirigiéndome a la url del PLC no me deja.

```
$file = file ("https://(URL del archivo)");

$nombre_archivo = "a.csv";

if (file_exists($nombre_archivo)){

     $file2 = implode("", $file); //Descarga del archivo
    header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = a.csv");

    sleep(4); // 4 segundos de espera para que dé tiempo a la descarga antes del borrado

    if (unlink($nombre_archivo)){  //Borrado del archivo
        echo "Archivo ($nombre_archivo) descargado y eliminado";
    }else{
        echo "Archivo ($nombre_archivo) no se pudo eliminar";
    }

}else{
    echo "Archivo ($nombre_archivo) no encontrado";
}
```

En las pruebas me dice que "el localhost rechazó la conexión" y cuando manipulo el launch.json me lleva a la carpeta anterior al archivo.

Es la primera vez que tengo que tocar un PLC de cualquier tipo y no tengo ni idea. Agradecería mucho si alguien me puede orientar, me da igual tener que cambiar de lenguaje de programación si hiciera falta.
Saludos!

Comment: ¿Puedes verificar temas de permisos sobre el file?, prueba emulando el file dentro de tu carpeta raíz de proyecto y utiliza (__dir__) para manejarte en la ruta del archivo

Comment: Gracias por el interés Orlando!
Al final he conseguido descargar el archivo usando C# con el metodo Webclient.DownloadFile("URL del archivo", @"directorio donde queremos descargarlo"). 
Ahora me falta la parte del borrado. He probado con File.Delete() pero al ser en un servidor y no en un directorio no me funciona.
Un saludo!